# Convert WHOIS Text Record to CSV

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to convert a text WHOIS record to CSV. Essentially, the file looks like this:

```
WHOIS Source: ARIN

IP Address:   8.8.8.8

Country:      USA - California

Network Name: LVLT-GOGL-8-8-8

Owner Name:   Google LLC

CIDR:         8.8.8.0/24

From IP:      8.8.8.0

To IP:        8.8.8.255

Allocated:    Yes

Contact Name: Google LLC

Address:      1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View

Email:        arin-contact@google.com

Abuse Email:  network-abuse@google.com

Phone:        +1-650-253-0000 

Fax:
```

I'm thinking that I handle each row as a variable, truncate the variable to fit the important data, then at the end, export it into a CSV.

so something like this:

```
ARIN,8.8.8.8,USA - California,LVLT-GOGL-8-8-8,Google LLC,...
```

I prefer batch, but if there's a powershell option that's fine too. I am not looking for the full code, but maybe just a line or two to address some of the rows. I can handle it from there.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? [SO] isn't a script writing service. Own research and serious coding attempts are expected. There ***are*** similar questions and solutions for batch as well for powershell.

Comment: I commend to your attention the PowerShell operator `-split`, the method `trim()`, and the cmdlet `Export-CSV`.

Comment: A one line PowerShell solution, converting `WhoIs.txt` to `WhoIs.csv` with headers `[PSCustomObject]((Get-Content .\WhoIs.txt -raw) -replace ': *','=' |ConvertFrom-StringData)|Export-Csv WhoIs.csv -NoTypeInfo`

Answer (score 1):

For each line, split in Header and Data, remove leading spaces in the data with `for /f "tokens=*"` and assemble a header line and a data line. Handle empty data fields with an additional `if <data> == <empty>` (an `else` is not needed because the `for ... %%c` loop doesn't execute the `do` part when the value (`%%b`) is empty.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in (whois.txt) do (
  set "hdr=!hdr!"%%a"," 
  if "%%b" == "" set "dta=!dta!"","
  for /f "tokens=*" %%c in ("%%b") do (
      set "dta=!dta!"%%c","
  )
)
(
echo %hdr%
echo %dta%
)>whois.csv
```

Instead of `in (whois.txt) do (` insert your actual `whois` command, like `in ('whois xxxxx') do (`

The quotes around each value protects against stray commas (like the `Adress:` line) and empty values (like the `FAX:` line)

(Sorry for full code, but it's difficult to split it into "hints" without getting too vague)

Answer (score 0):

In CMD Script it's fairly straight forward:

```
@(
  ECHO OFF
  SETLOCAL Enable DelayedExpansion
  SET "_SrcPath=C:\Temp\ArinWhois\RecordFiless"
  SET "_SrcFileGlob=*.txt"
  SET "_DstFilePath=C:\Temp\ArinWhois\ResultFile.csv"
  SET "_Header=1"
)

REM Loop the Files in the Path to allow us to know when moving from one to the next
FOR %%a IN (
  "%_SrcPath%\%_SrcFileGlob%"
) DO (
  REM on starting each file Set the Row variable to Empty
  SET "_Row="
  REM Loop the File and Extract the Terms
  FOR /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%A IN (%%a) DO (
    IF DEFINED _Header (
      REM Strip the leading and trailing spaces from the Header Term
      FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%b IN ("%%A") DO (
        IF NOT DEFINED _HeaderRow (
          SET "_HeaderRow=%%~nb"
        ) ELSE (
          SET "_HeaderRow=!_HeaderRow!,%%~nb"
        )
      )
    )
    REM Strip the leading and trailing spaces from the Term.
    FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%b IN ("%%B") DO (
      SET "_TmpTerm=%%~pnb"
      IF NOT DEFINED _Row (
        SET "_Row=!_TmpTerm:~1!"
      ) ELSE (
        SET "_Row=!_Row!,!_TmpTerm:~1!"
      )
    )
  )
  IF DEFINED _Header (
    SET "_Header="
    ECHO.!_HeaderRow!
    ECHO.!_HeaderRow!>"%_DstFilePath%"
  )
  ECHO.!_Row!
  ECHO.!_Row!>>"%_DstFilePath%"
)

PAUSE
TYPE "%_DstFilePath%"
PAUSE
```

The logical Flow is essentially this:

- Step 1: Loop the list of Files
- Step 2: Parse each line of Each file by using a Loop, splitting the Line by the `:`
- Step 3: If running the first time, we'll want to set up a header so we'll take the terms found on the first half of the line and create a header.  If we've already done that work, we skip it.
- Step 4: Whether a Header Term or a Row Term we'll want to remove both the Leading and Trailing spaces, to do this it's easiest to just use another loop and temp variable.
- Step 5: Output the Header (if Applicable)
- Step 6: Output the Row after Each File is processed.